# NoSuchMethodError Notification.Builder.build()

Tags: android

```
   Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("TITLE").setContentInfo("INFO")
            .build();
notificationManager.notify(ID,noti);
```

I have problem with that sample it is from google page. And I have exception NoSuchMethodError i don't know what's going on so I use old deprecated method with notifications noti.setLatestEventInfo but I'm sure there is another solution. Any ideas?

Comment: use Builder from support lib v4 (since you targeting API < 11) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: I'm using 16 and tested it on android 4.0.4 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Notification.Builder.build()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#build%28%29) is API level 16.

In 4.0.4,you should use [getNotification()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#getNotification()).

Or you had better use [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html).